# How to disable dhcpcd

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, networking, wifi, wireless

I'm trying to connect via Wi-Fi and to do so I have to disable `dhcpcd` but I couldn't. I tried:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f dhcpcd disable
```

But it didn't work 
I also tried to remove it using:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f dhcpcd remove
```

It still didn't work, any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd.service` will stop (deactivate) dhcpcd
`sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service` will prevent it from restarting.

Having said the above, I think this is a bad idea.
There are a few different network managers in use on Pi under Linux. `dhcpcd` performs well, and has been chosen by the Foundation for good reasons.

On another point, you should get used to `systemd`. It is now used by most GNU/Linux distributions. `sysV` is still partially used, but on the way out.

Comment: It gave some warnings but it worked.

Comment: *I think [disabling `dhcpcd`] is a bad idea* (...) *you should get used to `systemd`* → `systemd` has `systemd-networked`, which requires disabling `dhcpcd`.

Answer (score 1):

> This Answer is technically incorrect.
> You should follow [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
> or if you really want Static IP [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)

This is not a direct answer but going to be useful to anyone trying to set up their raspberry pi to use static IP, because /etc/dhcpcd.conf will in fact change the IP of raspberry PI, even if you set a static profile, if another device is using that IP on the network. This can be a big security issue for some projects.

In addition to disabling dhcpcd using systemctl, you can set a static IP by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`

The latest Raspbian distributions ship with this file empty, but I tested that after disabling dhcpcd, you can set the static IP you want to use by adding this to the end of `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.51
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```